# Asynchronous tasks in Django

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, async-await, telegram

I want to implement a telegram group parser (namely users) into the Django application. The idea is this, from the post request I get the name of the group entered into the form, I pass it to the asynchronous function (which lies in a separate file) and parsing starts. And so at a call of asynchronous function in view, constantly I receive errors. Such as "RuntimeError('The asyncio event loop must not change after connection", "RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'" etc. Please help me, how would this be better organized?

Function for parsing users below:

```
api_id =  **** 
api_hash = '*****' 
phone = '+******' 
client = TelegramClient('+********', api_id, api_hash)

client.start()


async def dump_all_participants(url):
    """Writes a csv file with information about all channel/chat participants"""
    offset_user = 0    # member number from which reading starts
    limit_user = 200   # maximum number of records transferred at one time

    all_participants = []   # list of all channel members
    filter_user = ChannelParticipantsSearch('')

    
    while True:
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(await client.get_entity(url),
            filter_user, offset_user, limit_user, hash=0))
        if not participants.users:
            break
        all_participants.extend(participants.users)
        offset_user += len(participants.users)

    all_users_details = []   # list of dictionaries with parameters of interest to channel members
    for participant in all_participants:
        all_users_details.append({"id": participant.id,
            "first_name": participant.first_name,
            "last_name": participant.last_name,
            "user": participant.username,
            "phone": participant.phone})
    
    df =  pd.DataFrame(all_users_details)
    csv_file_path = './data.csv'
    df.to_csv(csv_file_path, index=False)
```

Comment: Why you don't simply use celery for async task?

Comment: @Zilay Thought about celery but wanted to do without it. It's not such a big app to subdivide. But most likely I will have to use it. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You encountered the `Django` thread problem because calling an `async` function as you do opens a new thread that is occupied by `Django`. The problem is, you can't really mix Telethon code without using async views, and I'm not certainly sure if the issue will persists with Celery, so I really recommend upgrading to Django 4 version and try to use async views with ASGI.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll keep it in mind for the future. Already solved this problem with Celery, made it as a standalone application that interacts with the database. And I use Django just for the input form. Celery solved everything and there are no more problems with thread :)